# Version based data: Version column, extra tables or multiple databases?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a video game statistics database where much information needs to be linked to a given patch (version 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, etc). Some of the data pertains to all patches (such as a player's overall win count), and other information is patch dependent (such as a player's win count for the patch). There are hundreds of millions of matches per patch, and given that each match has ten players, the "matches_players" relationship table will have over a billion rows per patch. I can think of three solutions possible for storing this information:

1) One massive database with a "patch_id" column in the "matches" table. I assume that MySQL can easily calculate a player's kill count, etc for a given patch by joining with the "matches" table in queries?

2) One massive database with new tables named for each patch ("matches_2_4", "players_2_4", "matches_2_5", "players_2_5", etc).

3) Multiple databases, a master for storing shared info and one for each patch. This makes things the most organized visually. Will this affect performance? I've read that using multiple databases is simply a syntactical difference to MySQL and queries should be just as fast, even if I reference multiple databases.

One more thing... Patches are based on periods of time (new patches every few months). The "matches" table already has a "start_time" column. If using a single database with massive tables, should I make a "patch_id" column or just perform queries using "WHERE start_time > 154829350 and start_time < 157543076"?

I've read the answers to similar questions that have been posted, but most say that "it depends" and then explain based on the asker's situation, so I'd like to know people's thoughts about this one. Thanks guys.